# communication between windows mobile client and winforms application throw wcf

Tags: c#, winforms, wcf, visual-studio-2008, windows-mobile-6

i created a wcf service to receive gps coordinates from windows mobile 6 client and save them into data base.Every thing works fine but i'm trying to send some configuration from a winforms application to the windows mobile client.
Does any one have any idea?

Comment: actually i don't have any idea how to do it

Answer (score 0):

The WCF Service needs to be on a running Web Service (localhost is OK).

Once the WCF Service is created and running on your PC, Right-Click and add a Web Reference to your project.

[image: Web Reference]

Once that is done, create a client instance of your service so you can call the public methods you created in it.

The PC running the Web Service must be able to "see" your device. See if you can PING your device:

[image: ping]